# Google App Engine GREATER_THAN and LESS_THAN comparison operator not working

Tags: google-app-engine, comparison, operator-keyword

I am trying to pull data from an Entity called `latLongInfo` and trying to get all the results with the lattitude results within a certain range.  Below code should work but it's not:

```
Filter lowerLatF = new FilterPredicate("lat", FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN, botLat);
Filter topLatF = new FilterPredicate("lat", FilterOperator.LESS_THAN, topLat);
Filter twoFilter = CompositeFilterOperator.and(lowerLatF, topLatF);
Query rip = new Query("latLongInfo").setFilter(twoFilter);
PreparedQuery ripQ = datastore.prepare(rip);
List<Entity> llResult = ripQ.asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(15));
int sizeOfList=llResult.size();
```

The value of `botLat` is `40.94495459565217` and the value of `topLat` is `41.3797372043`.

In the Datastore that I am pulling the data from there's a result with `lat = 41.1623459` however, the code above doesn't find it and keeps giving me a `sizeOfList = 0`.

I should be getting at least one result but it's not returning it.  Is there something simple I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I was saving the lat as String rather than a numerical float or double.  Once i changed it to save doubles (these were actually converted to floats in the datastore) I was able to do the comparison without issue.

Decided to answer my own question...in case this helps anyone else.